# When does casting to `int` cause problems?

Tags: objective-c, 32bit-64bit

Recently (as of Xcode 6?) I've got hundreds of warnings where I am converting without a cast:

- from `NSInteger` to `int`
- from `NSUIntger` to `int`

If I were to add a cast:

- Under what conditions would this be problematic? Only if the number exceeds 32-bit integer max, right?
- Under what conditions would converting back the other be problematic? Only if the number is negative and we're going to `NSUInteger`?

Comment: Note: In this age of both 32/64 bit support, you really should minimize the use of `int`. Use the proper type based on the API you are using.

Comment: @rmaddy the concern is that replacing `int` with `NSInteger` is kind of a no-brainer (I think), but replacing `int` with `NSUInteger` can lead to problems and needs to be considered case-by-case (since int can go negative but NSUinteger cannot). But yes, for new code, you're right: minimizing use of int is the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://wpguru.co.uk/2013/11/how-to-covert-an-nsuinteger-nsinteger-into-an-int-value/) agrees with your first point-
"This is not a problem if your value is anywhere between 0 and 4,294,967,295 (or between −2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 respectively)."